# How to use sql function in prepared statement

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement, sql-function

I try to add 1 to an counter-field in Postgres/php.
But it seems not to work well with a query with parameters

My query is:

```
UPDATE calendar."event" SET "sequence"=$1,"id_calendar"=$2,"starttime"=$3,"endtime"=$4,"summary"=$5,"description"=$6,"remark"=$7,"id_address"=$8,"available"=$9,"changed"=$10,"auth_user"=$11 WHERE ("id" = 23)
```

The array with parameters:

```
'sequence' => 'sequence+1',
'id_calendar' => '1',
'starttime' => '2017-06-28 11:59:00',
'endtime' => '2017-06-28 18:00:00',
'summary' => 'test',
'description' => '',
'remark' => '',
'id_address' => '25',
'available' => '1',
'changed' => 'now()',
'auth_user' => '5',
```

The function for column 'changed' is working well.
But the sum for 'sequence' is giving an error.

```
'ERROR: 22P02: invalid input syntax for integer: "sequence+1"
```

I have tried extra quotes or adding a function like abs(). But nothing helps.
Google could not help also.

To prepare and execute queries I use:
 - pg_send_prepare()
 - pg_send_execute()

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a function call, but there is no need to bind `now()`.  You only need to bind variables (dynamic).  Just put the now() directly in your statement.

Comment: I see.... tx for your answer. So I cannot use functions in an prepared query :-(
Strange thing is, 'now()' has always worked fine; so that is why I thought the addition should work also

Comment: @flexJoly That's surprising to me as I would expect it to put in the database a literal `now()` rather than the current time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, with the syntax listed above, that you're trying to update an integer column with the value 'sequence + 1'. You'll need to calculate the value and provide that to your function, I.e. "Sequence"=>5. Look at your error, it's telling you exactly what the issue is.

The most likely more "correct" way of doing this would be to create an actual sequence and use the nextval() function on your query. No need to increment on your side when Postgres has a built in way of doing it better.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createsequence.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Indeed postgress can do this better, but it should not always do an addition. So it is easier to handle it with php, and then it is also under version-control (git).